# Let $A_{i}$ be a a collection of connected spaces, and assume $\bigcap A_i \neq \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Show that $\bigcup_{i \epsilon A} A_i$. is connected

I'm not sure how to even start going about this. If anyone had any advice on lemma's to look at or theorem's i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @coffeemath Yep sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it's not connected. Then there are two non empty disjoint open sets $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = \cup A_i$.

Notice that for every $A_i$, we must have either $A_i \subseteq A$ or $A_i \subseteq B$. Otherwise, $A_i \cap A$, $A_i \cap B$ form two non empty disjoint open sets that union up to $A_i$. So pick any $A_k$, and suppose WLOG that $A_k \subseteq A$. Now given any other $A_i$, either $A_i \subseteq A$ or $A_i \subseteq B$. But notice if $A_i \subseteq B$ we have $A_i \cap A_k = \emptyset$. Thus, $A_i \subseteq A$ as well. Thus, all of the $A_i$ are in $A$ which means $\cup A_i \subseteq A$, which is a contradiction as we assumed $B$ is non empty and $A \cup B = \cup A_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much this is a great help. Would you mind telling me how you went about proving it? i.e how you knew where to start? I'm having trouble figuring out how to start a lot of these proofs

Comment: Many times proof by contradiction and "chasing the definitions" to a contradiction gets you there. Of course this isn't as satisfying a direct proof and doesn't always work.